# External XML data to gridview

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview

I´m trying to get data (link) from an public XML file to my gridview.

I´m trying following, but can't get it done. Anyone can help me on that?

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=lebl&hoursBeforeNow=5"> </asp:XmlDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

RU

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the XML anyway so try this

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="WeatherList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Latitude" HeaderText="Latitude" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="WindDirectionSpeed" HeaderText="Wind Speed(kms)" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindWeatherGrid();
    }
}

private void BindWeatherGrid()
{
    var url = "http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=lebl&hoursBeforeNow=5";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);
    var metars = from wthr in doc.Descendants("METAR")
                  select new Metar()
                  {
                      Latitude = (string)wthr.Element("latitude"),
                      WindDirectionSpeed = (string)wthr.Element("wind_speed_kt")
                  };
    WeatherList.DataSource = metars;
    WeatherList.DataBind();
}
```

Namespaces used

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Helper Class

```
public class Metar
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string WindDirectionSpeed { get; set; }
}
```